# Date Timestamps and datetime64[ns, UTC] comparison in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I'm quite confused because of effect of this filtering process using pandas DataFrames. I'm trying to get rows that are in between some dates but my result DataFrame is empty. I'm sure data is there in that period.

`df.info()` returning that 'opentime' is type: `opendate 440383 non-null datetime64[ns, UTC]

Code snippet:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

current_date = pd.datetime.now()
t_delta_week = timedelta(days=7)
t_delta_year = timedelta(days=365)

#CurrentDate
date_start2020 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_week, unit='ms')
date_end2020 = pd.Timestamp(current_date, unit='ms')

date_start2020 = date_start2020.tz_localize('utc')
date_end2020 = date_end2020.tz_localize('utc')


#LastYearDate
date_start2019 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_year - t_delta_week, unit='ms')
date_end2019 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_year, unit='ms')

date_start2019 = date_start2019.tz_localize('utc')
date_end2019 = date_end2019.tz_localize('utc')


df2020_2019['opendate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2020_2019['opendate'], unit='ms') 
mask = (df2020_2019['opendate'] > date_start2020) & (df2020_2019['opendate'] <= date_end2020)
df_currYear = df2020_2019.loc[mask]

df_currYear
```

The returned DataFrame is empty

Thanks for help! :)

EDIT:

Maybe that could help: 'opendate' is generated column and is created using this code fragment:

```
import pandas as pd
fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
df2020_2019.dropna(subset=['opentime_TS'], inplace=True)
df2020_2019['opendate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2020_2019['opentime_TS'], utc=True, format=fmt, errors='ignore')
```

Additionally I've put some `head()` prints of 
[data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7DsW.png). I'm cannot provide record of df, because of privacy :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the empty df_currYear with a dummy df as df2020_2019, using `pd.date_range` to simulate 'opendate'. At first I thought this was a tz issue, however, this should raise a `TypeError` and it looks like you made sure everything is in UTC...

Comment: I'm add some details to question, maybe that could help. To be true, I've encountered TypeError before with sth like "cannot compare tz-aware and tz-dummy dates".  I've also tested between function with success:
df_lastYear = df2020_2019[df2020_2019["opendate"].between(date_start2019, date_end2019)], but still cannot do the same for year 2020 :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad. I've just get mind-blind because of focus on tz TypeErrors... I've taken wrong datasource that is already outdated :) Final solution which works with proper data:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
df2020_2019.dropna(subset=['opentime_TS'], inplace=True)
df2020_2019['opendate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2020_2019['opentime_TS'], utc=True, format=fmt, errors='ignore')
df2020_2019.info()

current_date = pd.Timestamp.now()
t_delta_week = timedelta(days=7)
t_delta_year = timedelta(days=365)

#CurrentDate
date_start2020 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_week, unit='ms')
date_end2020 = pd.Timestamp(current_date, unit='ms')

date_start2020 = date_start2020.tz_localize('utc')
date_end2020 = date_end2020.tz_localize('utc')


#LastYearDate
date_start2019 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_year - t_delta_week, unit='ms')
date_end2019 = pd.Timestamp(current_date - t_delta_year, unit='ms')

date_start2019 = date_start2019.tz_localize('utc')
date_end2019 = date_end2019.tz_localize('utc')

df2020_2019['opendate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2020_2019['opendate'], unit='ms') 

df_currYear = df2020_2019[df2020_2019["opendate"] > date_start2020]
df_lastYear = df2020_2019[df2020_2019["opendate"].between(date_start2019, date_end2019)]

df_currYear
```